# Prove that $h(x)$ verify all the properties just like the function $g(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

**Lemma**: Suppose that $g(x)$ is an infinitely differentiable function and $a_{1}, a_{2}, \ldots$ is a sequence of real numbers with $\cdots < a_{k} < a_{k-1} < \cdots < a_{1}$ so that

$\bullet$ $g(a_{i}) = 0$ for all $i$,

$\bullet$ There is a constant $C$ so that $a_{i} - a_{i+1} \leq C$ for all $i$, and

$\bullet$ $g(x)$ is neither bounded from above nor bounded from below on
$(-\infty,a_{1})$.

**Then the same is true** for $g'(x)$. That is there is a sequence $\cdots < b_{k} < b_{k-1} < \cdots < b_{1}$ so that $g'(b_{i}) = 0$, there is a constant $D$ so that $b_{i} - b_{i+1} \leq D$ for all $i$, and $g'(x)$ is neither bounded from above nor bounded from below on $(-\infty,b_{1})$.

Now, consider the function $$h(x)=g′(t+(1-t)x)(1-x)$$ where $t∈(0,1)$ is a parameter.

My **question** is: By using the above **Lemma**, prove that $h(x)$ verify all the properties just like the function $g(x)$.

Comment: should it be $|a_i-a_{i+1}|\le C$

Comment: @ellya: No, without absolute value.